# a planes resultant velocity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

a plane has a typical cruise speed of 567 mph when at 35,000 ft.  If the plane is heading NE and encounters a Wind of 100 mph blowing from west to east, what is the airplane’s resultant velocity

i know that this is like vector addition but the word problem is confusing me and i don’t know how to do it

Comment: Draw a diagram and create the necessary triangles and solve using trig.

Comment: i have tried drawing the triangle but i’m not sure how it should look

Comment: Per Andrew Chin's comment, pretend that the wind is **turned off** for an hour.  Then, at the end of an hour, pretend that in a microsecond, the wind blows you 100 miles to the east.  How far from the origin would you end up, and what is the angle that the [ending point <--> origin : line segment] makes with the *horizontal* (i.e. makes with a due east vector)?  **Note** that this approach **may** well be *aerodynamically erroneous*.  It is unclear to me whether the effect of a 100 mph west<-->east wind on (for example) a stationary object is identical to the effect on a plane going NE.

Comment: i figured it out, thx everyone